Amazon EC2 behind the ALB gives Cors Error
In my application I have the following setup:

I have a website i acquired from AWS route53 called: https://dailyenglishacademy.com
My web angular app is running on the s3 bucket.
I have a spring boot application running in a container on an ec2 instance behind the ALB.
Both s3 bucket and the Application load balancer is behind a cloudfront distribution.
I have a rule for transferring requests coming to 443 port of the ALB to ec2 instances 8080 port.
In my cloudfront dist. I have 2 rules, one is if i send a request to /api/* its redirected to ALB and otherwise to s3 bucket.
I try to make a signup request from website hosted by s3 bucket.

So when I make a request I get this error.

www.dailyenglishacademy.com/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dz9tc8yjwihu0.cloudfront.net/api/signuptoemaillist' from origin 'https://www.dailyenglishacademy.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I can assure that communication between ALB and ec2 works because /health url of the ec2 is checked by ALB to check the health of the ec2 instance and its running healthy. Btw, for my ALB, for testing purposes i made the inbound rule set 0.0.0.0/0 to see if it works.
also this is my java class for the controller:
private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DailyEnglishApi::class.java)

@PostMapping("/signuptoemaillist")
@CrossOrigin(origins = ["https://dz9tc8yjwihu0.cloudfront.net","https://www.dailyenglishacademy.com","http://www.dailyenglishacademy.com"])
fun signUpToEmailList(@RequestBody req: SignUpEmailRequest): ResponseEntity<Any> {
    logger.info("signuptoemaillist endpoint was called")

    try {
        signUpEmailToList.signUpToEmailList(req)
        return ResponseEntity<Any>(SignUpEmailResp(true), HttpStatus.OK)

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return ResponseEntity<Any>(SignUpEmailResp(false), HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}

